# Failed to deserialized json object

Tags: android, json, list, sharedpreferences, gson

I want to save list to Android SharedPreferences,but something wrong as log says.
My code here:

Save list to SharedPreferences.I wanna save a bean as object.

```
public static void putBookBean(Context ctx, List<BookBean> bookList) {
    if (sp == null) {
        sp = ctx.getSharedPreferences("config", MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(bookList);
    editor.putString(ConstantValue.BOOK_BEAN, json);
    editor.commit();
}
```

And Load list:

```
public static ArrayList<BookBean> getBookBean(Context ctx) {
    if (sp == null) {
        sp = ctx.getSharedPreferences("config", MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = sp.getString(ConstantValue.BOOK_BEAN, null);
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<BookBean>>() {
    }.getType();
    ArrayList<BookBean> arrayList = gson.fromJson(json, type);
    return arrayList;
}
```

This is my bean:

```
public class BookBean {
public String bookName;
public int bookBgSrc;

public BookBean(String bookName,int bookBgSrc){
    this.bookName = bookName;
    this.bookBgSrc =bookBgSrc;
}

public String getBookName(){
    return bookName;
}

public int getBookBgSrc(){
    return bookBgSrc;
}
```

}

And use :

```
Int mDatas[] = {R.drawable.shape_book_gold, R.drawable.shape_book_add};
String mInfos[] = {"我的账本", "添加账本"};
List<BookBean> mBookList;
mBookList = new ArrayList<BookBean>();
    for (int i = 0; i < mDatas.length; i++) {
        mBookList.add(new BookBean(mInfos[i], mDatas[i]));
    }
    if (SpUtils.getBookBean(getApplicationContext()) == null) {
        SpUtils.putBookBean(getApplicationContext(), mBookList);
    }

mRvAdapter = new BookSelectRvAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            SpUtils.getBookBean(getApplicationContext()));

mBookList.add(mBookList.size() - 2,
                        new BookBean("新增账本", R.drawable.shape_book_gold+""));
                SpUtils.putBookBean(getApplicationContext(), mBookList);
```

Log is here:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.chase.cn.money_of_my/activity.BookSelectActivity}: com.google.gson.JsonParseException: The JsonDeserializer com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$CollectionTypeAdapter@52899014 failed to deserialized json object [{"bookName":"我的账本","bookBgSrc":2130837618},{"bookName":"添加账本","bookBgSrc":2130837617}] given the type java.util.ArrayList<beans.BookBean>
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                     Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonParseException: The JsonDeserializer com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$CollectionTypeAdapter@52899014 failed to deserialized json object [{"bookName":"我的账本","bookBgSrc":2130837618},{"bookName":"添加账本","bookBgSrc":2130837617}] given the type java.util.ArrayList<beans.BookBean>
                                                                        at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializerExceptionWrapper.deserialize(JsonDeserializerExceptionWrapper.java:63)
                                                                        at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationVisitor.invokeCustomDeserializer(JsonDeserializationVisitor.java:88)
                                                                        at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationVisitor.visitUsingCustomHandler(JsonDeserializationVisitor.java:76)
                                                                        at com.google.gson.ObjectNavigator.accept(ObjectNavigator.java:106)
                                                                        at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContextDefault.fromJsonArray(JsonDeserializationContextDefault.java:64)
                                                                        at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContextDefault.deserialize(JsonDeserializationContextDefault.java:49)
                                                                        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:568)
                                                                        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:515)
                                                                        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:484)
                                                                        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:434)
                                                                        at utils.SpUtils.getBookBean(SpUtils.java:139)
                                                                        at activity.BookSelectActivity.initData(BookSelectActivity.java:61)
                                                                        at activity.BookSelectActivity.onCreate(BookSelectActivity.java:43)
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
```

Thank you for checking my code.

Comment: You'd better put the `BookBean` code out

Comment: BookBean is here.

Comment: Can you show how you are calling this two methods getBookBean() & putBookBean,specially getBookBean()

Comment: I use this two methods to an RecyclerView adapter.

Comment: String mDatas[] = {R.drawable.shape_book_gold, R.drawable.shape_book_add}; this line is not giving error? mDatas should be int not String?

Comment: It's Int, sorry.

Comment: I tried your code its running without any error.

Comment: My codes works, Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `BookBean` need to write like this.

```
public class BookBean {
    public String bookName;
    public long bookBgSrc;

    public BookBean(){

    }


    public BookBean(String bookName,long bookBgSrc){
        this.bookName = bookName;
        this.bookBgSrc =bookBgSrc;
    }

    public String getBookName(){
        return bookName;
    }

    public long getBookBgSrc(){
        return bookBgSrc;
    }

    public void setBookBgSrc(long bookBgSrc) {
        this.bookBgSrc = bookBgSrc;
    }

    public void setBookName(String bookName) {
        this.bookName = bookName;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't see any changes.

Comment: My carelessness,sorry. but I need int bookBgSrc.

Comment: problem still exist.

Comment: I changed a bit, you try

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList

Comment: `Type type = new TypeToken<List<BookBean>>().getType();   
        List<BookBean> arrayList = gson.fromJson(json, type);`

Comment: It works,and I change the methord    `public static List<BookBean> getBookBean(Context ctx) {}`  I really appreciate it. As a begineer, I have many things to learn. Thanks again!!!